# project.json scripts events can delete folders?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, project.json

I am trying to delete a folder on post compile but cant make rd or del commands to work. Is there a way to delete a folder and subfolders from the scripts events?

Answer (score 0):

Put the commands that you need in a batch or shell file and invoke that file in the post compile step

Answer (score 0):

Use **npm** and **gulp** task, that not depends on the OS

Add a **package.json** file in your project root with `gulp` and `gulp-rimraf` dependencies:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "your description",
  "name": "your project name",
  "readme": "yuour readme",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
  },
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "3.9.1",
        "gulp-rimraf": "0.2.0",
    },
    "scripts": {
        "gulp": "gulp",
    }
}
```

Add a **gulpfile.js** in your project root containing the cleanup task :

```
/// <binding Clean='clean' />
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp"),
        rimraf = require("gulp-rimraf");


gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
    return rimraf("path to js folder to delete", cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
    return rimraf("path to css folder to delete", cb);
});

gulp.task("default", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);
```

In your **project.json**, call the npm script :

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "precompile": "npm run gulp" // this will call the default gulp task
    },
}
```

For more information, you can read the doc about how to use gulp on the [asp.net docs site](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-gulp.html?highlight=task)
You can do the same using **grunt** instead of **gulp** if you want